# Python: Linear interpolation for CDS rates based on maturity represented in years

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to linearly interpolate a series of CDS rates. Below is the data I have available; it is represented as maturities and in years.

```
    Maturity    Company 1   Company 2
0   0.5 186.73  186.73
1   1.0 210.65  210.65
2   2.0 249.09  249.09
3   3.0 285.4   285.4
4   4.0 317.59  317.59
5   5.0 344.06  344.06
6   6.0 363.01  363.01
7   7.0 375.69  375.69
8   8.0 384.31  384.31
9   9.0 391.0   391.0
10  10.0    396.12  396.12
```

I am now trying to use this set of maturities and their CDS rate in a similar format to interpolate the rate; below is an example of the maturities I will need to interpolate.

```
    Maturity Years
28  0.10410958904109589
29  0.1863013698630137
30  0.27671232876712326
31  0.3561643835616438
32  0.4328767123287671
33  0.5260273972602739
34  0.5945205479452055
35  0.684931506849315
36  0.7753424657534247
37  0.852054794520548
38  0.9397260273972603
39  1.0164383561643835
40  1.104109589041096
41  1.1863013698630136
42  1.2728102189781023
43  1.35492700729927
44  1.4343065693430657
45  1.5136861313868615
46  1.6012773722627738
47  1.686131386861314
48  1.770985401459854
49  1.853102189781022
50  1.9434306569343067
51  2.02007299270073
52  2.10492700729927
53  2.184306569343066
54  2.2751540041067764
55  2.3572895277207393
56  2.433949349760438
57  2.518822724161533
58  2.6009582477754964
59  2.6830937713894594
60  2.7707049965776864
61  2.8528405201916494
62  2.940451745379877
63  3.0198494182067077
64  3.1047227926078027
65  3.1813826146475015
66  3.2749178532311065
67  3.3543263964950714
68  3.4309967141292446
69  3.521358159912377
70  3.6007667031763417
71  3.6801752464403066
72  3.7677984665936473
73  3.8526834611171963
74  3.940306681270537
75  4.019715224534502
76  4.101861993428258
77  4.186746987951808
78  4.274760383386581
79  4.351437699680511
80  4.4281150159744405
81  4.518484710178001
82  4.600638977635782
83  4.68553172067549
84  4.767685988133272
85  4.8498402555910545
86  4.940209949794614
87  5.0196257416704695
88  5.099041533546326
89  5.18667275216796
90  5.269847477512711
91  5.354712553773954
92  5.434102463824795
93  5.518967540086038
94  5.595619867031678
95  5.685960109503324
96  5.776300351974971
97  5.8529526789206106
98  5.940555338287055
99  6.017207665232695
100 6.10481032459914
101 6.186937817755182
102 6.275154004106776
103 6.357289527720739
104 6.433949349760438
105 6.5160848733744015
106 6.6009582477754964
107 6.685831622176591
108 6.7734428473648185
109 6.852840520191649
110 6.945927446954141
111 7.014373716632443
112 7.104722792607803
113 7.186858316221766
114 7.275022817158503
115 7.3571645877700025
116 7.433830240340736
117 7.513233951931853
118 7.600851840584119
119 7.685731670216002
120 7.7706114998478855
121 7.852753270459385
122 7.943109218132035
123 8.019774870702769
124 8.10465470033465
125 8.184058411925768
126 8.274917853231106
127 8.357064622124863
128 8.433734939759036
129 8.518619934282585
130 8.600766703176342
131 8.6829134720701
132 8.77053669222344
133 8.852683461117197
134 8.940306681270537
135 9.019715224534503
136 9.104600219058051
137 9.181270536692224
138 9.272523643603783
139 9.35191637630662
```

In the past, I have created log-linear interpolation functions that will allow me to interpolate discount rates based on maturities represented as dates, not as yearly numerical values; below is an example of that function.

```
def loglinearinterpolation(df, list_of_dates, dt_rng_name, rate_rng_name):
    asofDate = pd.to_datetime(list_of_dates)
    low_lim = df[df[dt_rng_name] <= asofDate].tail(1)
    upper_lim = df[df[dt_rng_name] >= asofDate].head(1)
    if low_lim.index == upper_lim.index:
        return low_lim[rate_rng_name].iloc[0]
    mat_dt_min = low_lim[dt_rng_name].iloc[0]
    mat_dt_max = upper_lim[dt_rng_name].iloc[0]
    y_min = low_lim[rate_rng_name].iloc[0]
    y_max = upper_lim[rate_rng_name].iloc[0]
    return np.exp(((np.log(y_max) - np.log(y_min))/((mat_dt_max - mat_dt_min).days))*(asofDate - mat_dt_min).days + np.log(y_min))

df_Libor_interpolated = pd.DataFrame()
df_Libor_interpolated = [(pd.to_datetime(x), loglinearinterpolation(df_libor_curve, pd.to_datetime(
    x), 'Dates', 'value')) for x in df_client_curve['Date'].unique()]
```

I now need to do a similar task using the same formula in the return function, except linearly, not log linearly; however, my code is breaking as the values I am feeding for dates are being converted to DateTime and providing numpy and timestamp comparison errors.

I have tried using the code below as a workaround; however, it is not providing me with the values my team expects.

```
[np.interp(x,df_cds['Maturity'],df_cds['Company 1']) for x in df_cds_interpolated['Maturity Years']]
```

Any guidance or insight on how I can modify the function and formula above to work with the input data I provided would be greatly appreciated!